# Storage density of a Deuterium-Helium 3 fusion pellet

Tags: fuel, engine-design, spacecraft-development, fuel-system, nuclear-pulse-propulsion

in a series I am working on I will be using a D-He3 fusion drive system (similar to the one in the expanse according to Project RHO). I am under the assumption that the fuel will be stored in a pellet form that will then be "injected" into the engine where a powerful laser will compress it until fusion occurs. (If this is not the case then please clarify).

The question: what is the density of such a pellet? As a reference, how much of this could be stored within a cubic meter?

Comment: People actually make these for laser fusion experiments I think. These are unfortunately paywalled but it's a start [1](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/laser-and-particle-beams/article/volume-ignition-of-inertial-confinement-fusion-of-deuteriumhelium3-and-hydrogenboronll-clean-fusion-fuel/B136FA6E4EB5971A1BEE62F6457D13EE), [2](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0741-3335/51/8/085003/meta), this one is not paywalled: [3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.05974.pdf)

Comment: Different but related [Using heated water as propellant for a DT-He3 fusion thruster](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43987/12102)

Comment: That is one of my posts for a different aspect I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Seems possible that you might fabricate pellets as you go.